# Приложение с цифровой подписью

Tags: delphi, сертификат, цифровая-подпись

Я уже окончательно запутался почитав форумы, поэтому лучше всего без демагоги поясните просто. Как можно подписать написанное приложение в Delphi имея сертификат?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет утилита SignTool от Microsoft, которая идет в составе пакета Microsoft SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx

Самый простой вариант подписи, когда Signtool выбирает сертификат с наибольшим сроком действия это выполнить такую команду:

```
signtool sign /a MyFile.exe
```

Если у вас сертификат в PFX файле, то подписать его можно, задав пароль к файлу:

```
signtool sign /f MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword MyFile.exe
```

Полная информация по командам Signtool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx